# How do I properly sample a table in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get a sample of my table, but continue to get the entire table in the results set.
select * from `dataset.my_table` TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (1 PERCENT) is giving all the records, not a sample.
It is not throwing any errors.  It has worked in the past, so I have not idea what I am doing wrong.

I tried running both with and without the tick marks around the data, and the exact same results in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

TABLESAMPLE in BigQuery works on the block level, not the row level, so if the blocks of your data are densely packed, you might get more data than expected. Similarly, if a block has fewer rows, you might get less than the desired percentage.

If you want a specific number of random rows, say 100 rows, you can combine ORDER BY RAND() with the LIMIT clause:

SELECT *
FROM `dataset.my_table`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100;

Comment: I appreciate that option, thank you, and will use it.  However, I'm getting ALL data back from my table, not just an overestimate.  I was concerned that something changed.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.  I am not sure if that works well with Bigquery.